# What is a good introductory text on statistical mechanics for math-student

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Here a "math-student" is an advanced undergrad or a 2nd-3rd-year grad student but only has taken the first-year undergraduate physics classes.

Ice-type models, Yang-Baxter Equations are of particular interest.

After reading the text, the reader should be able to have a deep understanding of, for example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0911.pdf).

What are good resources for these purposes?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am not sure it's a duplicate of the above-mentioned question, in view of the specific background of the OP. However, it is certainly a duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/4172) and may overlap with [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202885).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177539/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @YvanVelenik, Thankyou, this is exactly what I'm looking for