# Physics book recommendation for a mathematician studying statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I just started my PhD in statistics and I am very likely to defend my thesis on statistical mechanics. Having said that, as I am a mathematician by training, I do not have a strong background on physics and I would like to know which physics books you guys could suggest me so that I could profit the most such theory. I am particularly interested in the Ising model. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an [overarching book recommendation question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/resource-recommendations) which might be useful, since it links to some references on StatMech. Nevertheless, I think it still doesn't have a topic on StatMech for Mathematicians

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202885/2451

Comment: As a partial answer, I would suggest [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), which can be downloaded for free. It is mathematically rigorous (except for the introduction). Chapter 3 is on the Ising model. Of course, you may want to complement this with a book aimed at physicists if you want to know more about the physical background (although we do spend some time, especially in Chapter 1, on the physical motivations).

Comment: @YvanVelenik In the first place, thank you so much for your answer. My advisor has already suggested me your book (which I am already studying and I like it very much). Having said that, are you aware of any physics book which could fix my lack of knowledge in the subject (mainly in the context of the Ising model)?

Comment: It very much depends on what you'd like to learn. On the historical and physical significance of this model, I remember enjoying reading the series of papers [part 1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00407-004-0088-3), [part 2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-008-0039-5) and [part 3](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41287711). If you're more interested in specific physics aspects, you should provide more information on which you'd like to know more about.